# How to authenticate google token just like graph api of facebook?

Tags: authentication

I've authenticate facebook token by using facebook graph api for fb login, it worked out for me. I've used following request url

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=" + [token] + "&access_token=" + [client_id] + "|" + [client_secret]"
```

Now, all I want to do just like with google. From [Authenticate with a backend server](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) documentation to validate an ID token using the tokeninfo endpoint, I make an HTTPS POST or GET request to the endpoint, and passed ID token in the id_token parameter.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=[id_token]
```

But I'm getting `{ "error": "invalid_token", "error_description": "Invalid Value" }` response.